# Hide status bar until exit

Tags: android, statusbar

I have managed to hide status bar on start up. But whenever I touch the controls status bar shows up. To solve this I tried this code to hide it on every touches but it shows up first then it hides. This loop continues forever.

```
private View mContentView;
private View mControlsView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testgame);

    mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.hide();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE 
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
        }
    });
```

I have also tried to change theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` but still hides it until I touch controls. I want to hide it until I exit the application. It is possible to do it without root permissions because most of games that I played can hide it until I exit the game or swipe down on

Answer (score 0):

I have just found solution on [this](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/01/how-to-hide-android-status-bar-programmatically.html) page that hides status bar permanently.

Firstly I added this `import android.view.WindowManager;`.

Then here is my `OnCreate` function:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testgame);

    //Hide status bar
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 

    //Hide action bar
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }

}
```

And this code helps you to show status bar again

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);// Show status bar
```